Isomorphism in codimension $1$ and Cartier divisor
We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X,Y$ be normal projective varieties, and let $f: X\dashrightarrow Y$ be a birational map among them.
Assume that $f$ is an isomorphism in codimension $1$, that is the induced birational map $f_*: Z_1(X)\to Z_1(Y)$ is an isomorphism, where by $Z_1(X)$ we denote the free abelin group of prime divisors of $X$. Set $f^*:= f_*^{-1}$.
I think that $f^*$ does not restrict to an ismorphism at the level of Cartier divisors, that is given $D$ Cartier on $Y$, $f^*(D)$ may not be Cartier on $X$, but I cannot come up with an example.

For example, let $Y$ be a 3-dimensional quadratic cone and let
$$
f \colon X \to Y
$$
be one of its small resolutions. Since $f$ is small, it induces an isomorphism of class groups of Weil divisors, but while every Weil divisor is Cartier on $X$, this is not so on $Y$.
